# Python List Modifying Directly

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
lines = [["absb asdjhasd", "sadjhj sdhjsdh"], ["asjhjhad asdasd", " ashjhfdj asdasd"]]
for z in lines:
    for l in z:
        l = l.split()

print lines
```

How can i achieve that lines now contain the splits? It seems that there is a copy somewhere? Python 2.7

Comment: i want to replace each string with it's split. but this throws an error

Comment: when you do `l = l.split()` it doesn't change the actual variable `lines`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`l.split()` returns the split result without affecting the original string object, and `l =`rebinds just the variable, not the list entry.

You'd have to track the index too:

```
for z in lines:
    for index, l in enumerate(z):
        z[index] = l.split()
```

or you could use a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to rebuild the lists with the strings split:

```
lines = [[l.split() for l in z] for z in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to replace string with its splits

```
lines = [[l.split() for l in line] for line in lines]
```